# How do I load XML and XSD into dataset?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

I have XSD and XML file and when I load these XML and XSD files should be into Dataset.
I shared the code that am using. What else do I have to add to get the result?

```
string imp = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\sateesh\Download\Ex\Imp.xml");

string pattern = @"(</?)(\w+:)";

string out = Regex.Replace(imp, pattern, "*6");

StringReader reader = new StringReader(out);

XDocument docum = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(out);

XmlSchemaSet schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();

schemas.Add("urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:CoreComponentTypeSchemaModule:2", @"C:\sateesh\Download\Ex\file.xsd");
```

Comment: @er-sho Can u please give me the result if know

Comment: Funny, I don't see a `DataSet.ReadXml()` anywhere?

Comment: @Caius Jard Thank you. I didn't completed the whole task. so I asked for the whole Answer to display it on console with dataset format

Comment: you cant really (easily) display a dataset on the console(dos window).. are you sure this is what you meant?